# Issues upgrading MySql 5.0 to 5.1

Tags: mysql

I was doing some server updates and stupidly decided I should get the latest version of MySql. I had version 5.0 installed. Server is Windows Server 2003. I realize this is probably not the recommended upgrade route.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Stopped the 5.0 service
- Installed 5.1
- Deleted 5.0 service
- Configured 5.1 with same config as 5.0 with config wizard
- Started 5.1 service
- Copied data from MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\data to AppData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\data
- Ran mysql_upgrade
- Recreated users/privileges.

Two of my databases work and two don't. The two that do have files in their data folders with extensions .frm, .myd, .myi. The two that don't only have .frm files.

What do I need to do to get the non-working databases going?

Edit: I suppose I should clarify 'not working'. The non-working ones show up in the MySql Administrator and phpMyAdmin, but they have no tables listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't copy the `ibdata1` file. I stopped the service, copied that file from the old data directory, restarted and it's working. Huzzah